# How can Word replicate a table, without requiring me to copy and paste?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm shunning copying and pasting. How can Word automatically replicate the checklist ([here-from](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/typefaces/typographic-checklist)) in a Word document as many as times as it can fit in one page?

[image]

Doubtless I can't just copy and paste a table into Labels.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Besides copy-paste, you may also put the table into a
[Quick part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-quick-parts-and-autotext-in-word-7a527697-058f-4967-b8f1-aae0774e4813):

> You can use the Quick Part Gallery to create, store, and reuse pieces of content, including AutoText, document properties (such as title and author), and fields. These reusable blocks of content are also called building blocks. AutoText is a common type of building block that stores text and graphics. You can use the Building Blocks Organizer to find or edit a building block.

You may then insert the quick part as many times as you like into the document.